# Link to user profile isn't visible from chat if number of rooms is high

Tags: bug, chat

I tried to navigate to a user's profile from chat room.

But since the number of rooms in which the user is joined is large enough, the link is not visible and the box is not scrollable.

Even if we scroll the window to top, the box stay the same. I think it is because `position:fixed`

[image]

Usually the link to user profile is found above the list of rooms.

This is another user's details from chat.

[image]

Comment: +1. I ran into this bug just the other day.